# Initialize a Transactional Replication from a Backup of subscription

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

I had a transactional replication in SQL server 2012. people changed the data inside the subscription database. so changes has been added to subscription from:
1- my publication 
2- people who inserted their own data directly into subscription database.

I wana rebuild my replication, is there any way to rebuild replication using my subscription database which have users data?

Thanks,
Babak

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152560.aspx) under the subheading "Databases at the Subscriber".

But the longer answer is that you should design your replication topology in such a way so as to make the subscription database completely expendable. That is, if you have data that the users are entering directly into that database, either put it in separate tables (and put those tables on separate a separate filegroup) or, better, put those tables in a separate database completely and create views/synonyms to those tables in your subscriber database.